Wisdom requirements for high-level Templar spells?
In the Dark Sun rulebook (DSR), page 33 shows the spell progression chart for Templars. Unlike the priest spell progression chart on page 33 of the Player's Handbook (Table 24), the Templar spell progression doesn't indicate that 17/18 wisdom is needed to cast 6th/7th level spells. However, the templar is a priest class.
Do templars have the same wisdom requirements as clerics/druids for high level spells, or is there some exception I'm missing? I assume the answer is yes, but I can't find anything explicitly addressing it in the DSR (or the revised edition) or the Earth, Air, Fire and Water supplement book.

The ability score requirement for 6th and 7th level spells is specific to the 2e PH Priest Spell Progression table and, as mentioned, is notably absent from the Templar Spell Progression table. The DS campaign setting rulebook refers to features from the 2e PH, like bonus spells from having a higher Wisdom score, and mentions they are governed by the rules in the PH. However, there's nothing indicating that Wisdom would limit your Templar spell progression.
